# Hierarchical Data Grouping the Child and Grandchild Nodes Based on Parent Nodes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm having the hierarchical data as shown below:

```
hierarchyID  hierarchylevel    Name
0xB6               1           President
0xB6B0             2           Manager
0xB6B580           3           Project Head
0xB6B5AC           4           QA LEAD
0xB6B5AD60         5           SSE
0xB6B5B4           4           SE
```

The hierarchical tree structure for the above data as shown below:

```
            President   
                |
             Manager    
                | 
           Project head 
                |
       QA LEAD       SE     
          |
         SSE
```

I am trying to display the data as shown below using SQL SERVER 2012

```
Level1      Level2    Level3         Level4           Data
President                                             Manager
President   Manager                                   Project head
President   Manager   Project head                    QALEAD
President   Manager   Project head                    SE
President   Manager   Project head   QALEAD           SSE
```

Could you please help me how to write a SQL query for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
DECLARE @Example TABLE ([hierarchyID] hierarchyid, [hierarchylevel] int, [Name] varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @Example ([hierarchyID], hierarchylevel, Name)
SELECT 0xB6, 1, 'President' UNION ALL
SELECT 0xB6B0, 2, 'Manager' UNION ALL
SELECT 0xB6B580,3, 'Project head' UNION ALL 
SELECT 0xB6B5AC,4, 'QA LEAD' UNION ALL
SELECT 0xB6B5AD60, 5, 'SSE' UNION ALL
SELECT 0xB6B5B4, 4, 'SE'

SELECT 
  MAX(CASE WHEN e2.hierarchylevel=1 AND e2.hierarchylevel<e1.hierarchylevel THEN e2.Name ELSE NULL END) as level1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN e2.hierarchylevel=2 AND e2.hierarchylevel<e1.hierarchylevel THEN e2.Name ELSE NULL END) as level2, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN e2.hierarchylevel=3 AND e2.hierarchylevel<e1.hierarchylevel THEN e2.Name ELSE NULL END) as level3, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN e2.hierarchylevel=4 AND e2.hierarchylevel<e1.hierarchylevel THEN e2.Name ELSE NULL END) as level4, 
  e1.Name as Data
FROM @Example e1
INNER JOIN @Example e2 ON e1.hierarchyID.IsDescendantOf(e2.hierarchyID)=1
WHERE e1.hierarchylevel>1 
GROUP BY e1.Name, e1.hierarchylevel
ORDER by e1.hierarchylevel
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. Does my answer give you what you wanted?

Comment: then could you accept the answer by ticking it please. thanks